# NIntegrate fails to converge around a value out of integration range

Tags: numerical-integration

This is the function that I am trying to integrate, I have interpolated it for best results (would rather not):

[image: The integrand]

There is a 'singularity' around 0, but I get the warnings and bad results even when integrating from $10^8$. Starting after the peak (say $1.5 \cdot 10^8$) does not help.

The error I am getting is:

> NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t near {t} = {5.3144*10^7}. NIntegrate obtained 1.7414`5.*^22 and 4.0786`5.*^18 for the integral and error estimates.

When I lower `PrecisionGoal` from 5 to 2, there is no warning message but the result is very much off the known value.

Comment: The function? Also you mention "far from the known value". How did you take this value?

Comment: Maybe rescale your function and your arguments, to a more natural range. Your argument is of the order 10^8 and the values are of the order of 10^-17.

Comment: Please show us the *expression* for the function you are trying to integrate, rather than just the plot; also show us how you interpolated it, and what expressions you use for the integral. Finally, what is your question exactly?

Comment: You can use `Integrate` on an `InterpolatingFunction`.  It usually works better.

Comment: Since you know the function is well behaved in the region of interest you can always just manually sample and use trapezoidal rule, foregoing `NIntegrate`s adaptive sampling and convergence checks of course. related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48360/2079